# Linker: Enforce symbol ordering in resulting binary

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker

I am building a library which roughly boils down to this:

```
// foo.c
extern void func();

int main() {
 // ...
}
```

I compile with `gcc -o foo func.o foo.c`.
This results in a binary where the symbol `func` is before `main` (i.e. has lower address).
However if I add optimization, f.e. `-O3` the linker decides to place `func` after `main`.

Is there a way to enforce this order?

Comment: Why do you need a specific order?

Comment: There is a another [discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc) that may address what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Some linkers seems to store their symbols by a key-value table with the hashed symbol as key. And when it comes to allocation, they might use the sequence in the hashed table, which might not be the sequence in which the symbols were encountered.

I never found a way to control this behavior. It happened to me with global variables.

You might get some control if you use a specific linker script and assign segments/sections to the functions.

Answer (score 0):

The order of symbols can be controlled by orderfile as well as linker scripts.

Compiler can only reorder symbols in a translation unit but not across. For that you need linker support.

Some linkers (BSD linker, lld, and probably mold) support order file. You can find more about it in [ndk documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/orderfile)